# How to set up different web server config for different team members in Visual Studio Asp.net Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a different developer, besides me, working on a Asp.net project (.net 4.5) on Visual Studio. The problem is that I use http://localhost/MyProject as my local server url, while he uses http://localhost:51123, probably because default port is already taken by another server.

The problem is when he commits a change to .csproj file, it change this configuration for me , and i have to change it back. And he's probably having the same problem when I change.

Is there a way for us to use different webserver, while allowing us to commit changes do .csproj file? (For when we add a new class or page, for instance).

How do you deal with that in your projects?

Comment: Accept their version so you won't have changes anymore. Then migrate away from .NETFramework 4.5 towards .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 entries in appsettings configuration like

"AWebserver" : "AProject",
"BWebserver" : "BProject"

where the url is passed use the Configuration object to read from the appsettings with your particular server key. It will make it a bit easy to
as you only have to change the key that is being passed in the configuration object.

Comment: And how do I change this configuration ? I forgot to tell I'm using .net framework 4.5

Comment: You can use the following snippet:

make a appsettings.json file in your project with the keys that I have mention above.

in your project use the snippet below and read from appsettings and everywhere you need the server url use the configuration object you get from the below snippet. so everytime you guys push or do work you just need to change the key that being passed in the configration object.






var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
              .AddJsonFile(@"<path to appsettings.json>");

var configuration = builder.Build();
var url = configuration["AWebServer"];